# YouTube API LiveChat new message notification

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am interested in following the [Live Chat Messages](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) of a [live video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

But the only method I could find of following the new messages is querying the same page of result until it is filled and then get the next one.

Which also means, my application won't be able to "see" the new messages until after I request once again the chat messages.

Is there any way to have YouTube "notify" (generic term here) my application of the presence of a new message in the chat (WebSocket / Long Polling) ? Or will I have to query for new messages on a set timer ?

Comment: did you find a solution? or settle for for just making network request every (x seconds)

Comment: Nope, youtube API doesn't support that, you have to make a query every x seconds.